# Label appearing out of size in iOS5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, uilabel

I am creating an app for both ios5 and ios6. I have a label, it appears correctly in iOS6 like this:

[image]

Same label in iOS5, looks like this:

[image]

What could be the reason?

The properties set in the xib file are 1) line breaks: word wrap 2) autoshrink: minimum font size 5 and tighten  letter spacing 3) no of line enabled: 4

What am i doing wrong? Need some guidance. Thanks

Comment: Probably a different initial font.

Comment: same initial font. all the same. When i run it in iOS5, it is different from iOS6. that is all. very strange...

Comment: Check the autoresize stuff in the view that the label sits in (not the label itself).  Something different there between 5 and 6.

Comment: I think Label chages its font size, check it in code lavel